# LazyLoader delay not working

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'm using [LazyLoader](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_timeout.html) plugin.

```
<img src="http://www.bostonbakesforbreastcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sun.jpg" data-original="http://www.bostonbakesforbreastcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sun.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="BMW M1 Hood" style="display: block;">
```

And my jQuery code:

```
     $(function() {          
     $("img").lazyload({
         event : "sporty"
     });
 });
 $(window).bind("load", function() { 
     var timeout = setTimeout(function() { $("img").trigger("sporty") }, 10000);
 });
```

But Lazyloader not working on this structure. Please see this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/97EJE/

What's my problem and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) the `src` attribute should contain url of the placeholder image (not the original image) and `data-original` should contain url of the original image. Currently you have both pointing to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved problem. When i change min.js file to main js and added .css files, it works!